# How to set initial value for radautocomplete in nativescript?

Tags: telerik, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Here is What I'm doing:
**Template:**

```
      <RadAutoCompleteTextView
        class="autocomplete"
        :items="regions"
        loaded="onLoaded"
        completionMode="Contains"
        @textChanged="textChanged"
        returnKeyType="done"
      />
```

**Script:**

```
      onLoaded() {
        this.$refs.autocomplete.addToken(
          new TokenModel(this.$store.state.profile.region),
        );
      },
```

But it doesn't work, as in, I don't get any preselected value for region.
I'm using nativescript-vue, How can I get a preselected value for my autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a `@` to `loaded` because it is an event. The `onLoaded` function should work as it is correctly adding a new token.